# I cannot run more than 117 urls

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

i was trying to run multiple urls at the same time to check if they are offline or online. but after many minutes this error appeared. im guessing that it can only run up to 117 links at a time? is there a fix for this one?

Error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 117 out of bounds for length 117

can someone help me with this error?

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class BrokenLink {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Robot rob = new Robot();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Broken Link Checker");
        JButton runUrls= new JButton("Run");
        JLabel urlText = new JLabel(); //Initialize Label
        JTextArea urlTextContainer= new JTextArea(); //Initialize Text Area
        runUrls.setBounds(250, 275, 100, 50); // X,Y,Height,Width
        urlText.setText("Enter URLs Here: ");
        urlText.setBounds(30, -10, 200, 100);
        urlTextContainer.setBounds(30,55,520,215);
        frame.add(runUrls);
        frame.add(urlText);
        frame.add(urlTextContainer);
        frame.setSize(600,400);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        runUrls.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\awoo\\eclipse-workspace\\KeywordSearch\\chromedriver.exe");
                WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                HttpURLConnection huc = null;
                int respCode = 200;
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String[] urls = urlTextContainer.getText().split("\n");
                driver.get(urls[0]);
                try {
                    huc = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(driver.getCurrentUrl()).openConnection());
                    huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                    huc.connect();
                    respCode = huc.getResponseCode();
                    if (respCode != 200) {
                        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                for(int i = 1; i < urls.length; i++) {
                    rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                    rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
                    ArrayList<String> newtab = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
                    driver.switchTo().window((String) newtab.get(i));
                    driver.get(urls[i]);
                    try {
                        huc = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(driver.getCurrentUrl()).openConnection());
                        huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                        huc.connect();
                        respCode = huc.getResponseCode();
                        if (respCode != 200) {
                            System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
                        }
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        }

    }
```

Comment: what's the `urls.length`?